# how to streaming h.264 video send to WOWZA using rtsp with live555

Tags: ios, h.264, rtsp, wowza, live555

I am new for capturing video, encoding in h.264, WOWZA server.

I have checked so many solutions on stack-overflow and google but not get perfect that I can use.

**Basic functionality:**

- continue capturing from iPhone (Video should be in h.264 encoded)
- using live555 library, generate RTSP url
- send that same video to WOWZA server for live-broadcast video

**Note:** Video should be continuously play on server from iphone device without major delay.

**My Question:**

- How to capture video which is encoded in h.264 format?
- How to integrate live555 library to VideoCapture class for generate RTSP URL?
- How to send that video to WOWZA using RTSP protocol?

For capturing video on ios am using AV Framework.

Please correct me if my way of think is wrong.

Thanks,
Punita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully compile both MobileVLCKit and Live555 library in same project. 
Solution:

1. I have re-compile both library with same Architecture (armv7 & armv7s) and generate DynamicFramework.
2. And Then used into same xcode project.

Comment: how you have done that? is there any library to help us with this? I want to learn to stream with WOWZA.

Comment: Yes, live555 library is there for stream with WOWZA

Comment: how to work with live555, do you have any reference?

Comment: @Punita I need your help. I also want to implement streaming h.264 video and send to **WOWZA** using rtsp. I have found [VideoCoder](https://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore) library for RTMP not rtsp. How did you use Live555 library? can please you send me sample code/Project?  my email id id bhaveshtandel17@gmail.com

Comment: Sorry I can't give you project sample code, hence it is break company's policy. I have write custom cpp class which start injector connection to Wowza server and using H264VideoStreamDiscreteFramer class I have encoded normal stream to H264 format. you can check test example given inx Live555 lib source code.

Comment: Thanks for reply. How had you created normal stream using AV Framework? or had u used other library? Thanks in advance. can i catch ur emailID for further communication? It would be helpful.

Comment: See this article on Wowza. I am using http://www.gdcl.co.uk/2013/02/20/iOS-Video-Encoding.html Video Encoder library for encoding frame into h264 and then send to Live555 RTSPClient. Hope this will helps you. Thanks punita

Comment: Hi Punita, what encoder you are using? Are you doing Push? I am stuck at the moment pushing stream to Wowza - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38745126/video-stream-nvr-to-wowza-cloud-instance can you help please?